# Order information is replaced by an unknown U.S. address

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

Recently I discovered a very strange thing going on in Magento store.
Some kind of virus or something is changing order information.

[image]

As you can see order is from United States. I tried ordering myself, typed in random order info like sdfsdfsdfs. But when I looked up in orders found this. Any suggestions what can I do about it? I'm very lost on this one, never happened before.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `Lithuanian`  Locale pack by default ,try to change locale English from footer or just go to

```
system > config > (general) general > local options > locale > english (US)
```

[image: Check image]

Comment: What locale has to do with anything? Like i said that you can see random generated delivery address, and how is it possible i don't know.